# Merging XML Files together into merged.xml file

Tags: xml, batch-file, xslt, merge

I will try to make my question as short as possible and with every detail needed..

I have a folder with MANY XML files and I need to merge all them together to have only one XML with all the details inside each one of them (merged.xml)

I would like to make that merge using XSL transform and a batch file

Examples of XML files:

File1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Errors>
<Error>
<Number>1</Number>
...Some other elements...
</Error>
</Errors>
```

File2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Errors>
</Error>
<Number>2</Number>
...Some other elements...
</Error>
</Errors>
```

Batch file code used to run XSL transformation on files:

```
for %%f in (File*.xml) do (
msxsl "%%~nf.xml" merge.xsl >> "merged.xml"
)
pause
```

I tried this XSL transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Errors">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="//*/Error"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However the output (merged.xml) file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Errors>
<Error>
<Number>1</Number>
...Some other elements...
</Error>
</Errors>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Errors>
<Error>
<Number>2</Number>
...Some other elements...
</Error>
</Errors>
```

The needed (merged.xml) file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Errors>
<Error>
<Number>1</Number>
...Some other elements...
</Error>
<Error>
<Number>2</Number>
...Some other elements...
</Error>
</Errors>
```

Sorry for making it long!!

Thanks in advance :) 
Looking forward you answer

Comment: Have you considered using [Oliver Becker's merge algorithm](https://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/merge/merge.xslt.html) rather than writing your own?

Comment: I think Oliver Becker's merge algorithm merges only two files together

Comment: Currently, your XSLT transformation does not seem to merge _anything_. It simply transforms a single source XML, as far as I can see. Then, because you concatenate all the resulting XML files, it looks as if you had merged them. Therefore, it would be a good start to try and merge two files.

Comment: I found a way to merge two files but the problem comes when I need to merge more than two files found in a specific directory...

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is not the tool to use.  Based on your desired results, you just want to concatenate all the files together, with the caveat that the resulting file is a well-formed XML document.  Basic algorithm:

- For each file, remove `<?xml?>` processing instructions, `<Errors>`, and `</Errors>` tags.
- Concatentate all files together
- Prepend `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><Errors>` to concatentated output.
- Append `</Errors>` to concatendated output.

These steps can likely be streamlined by using the proper tool: Perl, Python, et.al.

Just cuz the data is XML does not mean you have to use an XML tool to get the job done.